# yacc-how to write yacc code for checking balanced parentheses

Tags: c, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

It should give valid for
()
()()()()
(()()()(()))

And Invalid for
(
(((
()())

YACC CODE:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int yylex();
int yyerror(char* err);
extern FILE* yyin;
%}

%token OPENING CLOSING

%%
stmt : S {printf("Valid \n"); return 0;}
S    : OPENING S CLOSING S
|  ;
%%

int main(){
yyin=fopen("input.c","r");
yyparse();
return 1;
}
int yyerror(char* err){
printf("Invalid\n");
return 1;
}
```

LEX CODE:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

%}

%%
'\('  {return OPENING;}
'\)'  {return CLOSING;}
.     {return yytext[0];}
%%

int yywrap(){
return 1;
}
```

It's printing valid for every input even for strings like
(
()(
And also please mention about some good resources to start with

Comment: What’s with all the backslashes?

Comment: @user207421: The backslashes are an artifact of Stack Overflow’s UI. Some defect was introduced a few months ago in which, when a user enters code in a certain way (I do not know the details), the UI inserts backslashes before certain characters.

Comment: High time it was fixed then. This is a computer programming site. We shouldn’t have to put up with the site defacing code. @EricPostpischil

Comment: @user207421: Writing a comment will not get it fixed. You need to contact Stack Overflow administrators.

Comment: @OP You can get rid of the rules for OPENING and CLOSING and just use `'('` and `')'` directly in the yacc grammar file, as long as your final lex rule is `. return yytext[0];` Same for any other single-letter special character. It makes the grammar much more readable and saves you lex rules as well, which economizes on space.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've been using this site for 14 years and I have no idea how to do that. I assume they are aware of their own bugs?

Answer (score 4):

The first problem you have is that `'` characters don't mean anything to lex, so having them in your match patterns will look for a literal `'` in the input.  Since you have none, your rules won't match and you'll be giving undefined tokens to your parser.

The second problem is that putting `return 0;` in an action causes the parser to immediately return success when it occurs.  Since an action can be reduced whenever it is in a context when it can appear regardless of lookahead (due to default reductions), this causes your parser to print `Valid` and exit if the first token seen is anything other than `OPENING`.

In order to determine the success of a parser (or not), you need to check the return value of `yyparse()` -- it returns 0 on success and non-zero for failures (1 for invalid input and 2 for running out of memory).  So your parser should be:

```
%%
stmt : S
S    : OPENING S CLOSING S
|  ;
%%

int main(){
    if (!(yyin=fopen("input.c","r")) {
        /* ALWAYS check the return value of fopen */
        printf("can't open input.c\n");
        return 1; }
    if (yyparse() == 0) {
        printf("Valid\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Combine that with fixed lexer patterns:

```
"("    {return OPENING;}
")"    {return CLOSING;}
[\n ]  ;  /* ignore newlines and spaces */
.      {return yytext[0];}
```

and things should work more like you expect